# sort, mplayer and xargs

Tags: xargs, mplayer

I have a directory full of music files that I want to play in mplayer.  I want to play these files in order of their track number which is the forth field (space separated) in their filename.  I know I could do something like this:

```
ls | sort -nk4 | playlist
```

and then

```
mplayer -playlist playlist
```

but I would like to be able to do it without creating a playlist file.  The best I have so far is

```
ls | sort -nk4 | xargs -I{} mplayer {}
```

This seems to work but I am unable to use any of the normal mplayer controls.  I am curious if this is possible.  It seems it should be as you can type

```
mplayer songA.flac songB.flac songC.flac...
```

and it works fine.

Comment: I think the *playlist* approach is pretty good.  You should write a small shell script that creates a temporary playlist and plays that.  Delete the temporary playlist at the end of the script.  You can use `mktemp` to create a temporary filename for the playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `mplayer` is after a pipe, its `std input` is connected to the pipe now and not your keyboard, so the `mplayer`'s controls stop working - try this instead:

```
eval mplayer $( printf "%q\n" * | sort -n -k4 )
```

or if your `ls` has `-Q` (quote) option:

```
eval mplayer $( ls -Q | sort -n -k4 )
```

- However note that the best way is to use temp files as suggested. They offer more flexibility, avoid the quoting issues and you can remove them after you're done. Place them under `/tmp`.
- The quoting specifier `%q` of `printf` quotes the filenames - songs' names can have all kinds of characters in them.
- `eval` is need to strip the extra layer of quoting, so `mplayer` sees just the properly quoted filename.

Kinda messy as you see, so I'd again recommend using temp files ( been there, done that :).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU parallel you would do this:

```
ls | sort -nk4 | parallel --tty -Xj1 mplayer
```

This will work even if your file names contain space.

Comment: Note: `-j1` (one job at a time) is redundant when using `--tty`. I use `ls | shuf | parallel --tty -X mplayer`

Comment: (Yep, `-j1` is default for `--tty` for newer versions of GNU Parallel`)